# Select an array from a 3D Array and change it in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 3D array

```
int[,,] array3d = new int[x,y,z];
```

now I want to select all the numbers from z
so `array3d[x,y,0]`, `array3d[x,y,1]` ... `array3d[x,y,z]`
and want to replace them with a seperate array `int[] array`
to have something like

```
int[x,y,] array3d = array;
```

Comment: With a [multi-dimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays), you'll need to copy the new values across. Are you sure you didn't want a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) instead?

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding things, but it seems that to replace all (x,y) for each z, you'd need a 2d array to replace them, not a 1d one. (e.g. Thinking of a 4x4 Rubik's Cube where Y is bottom to top, X is left to right and Z is front to back: (X,Y) represents a vertical left-to-right slice.)